# Getting Django to run a main.py file

Tags: python, django

I've written a scientific program in python which outputs a .png and a .pdf
I would like to execute this main.py file from a web interface, with a nice big button saying GO and then display the .png and download a .pdf

I'm using a Django framework to serve the page saying GO. How do i get it to:

1. run my main.py file?
2. return the .png file to html template?
3. download the file which is generated by the main.py script?

Thank you internet

Comment: Have you ever worked with Django?

Comment: Just in case of not, please try the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) it is really easy to understand

Comment: yes, but I've never integrated a django project with any other python projects

Comment: encapsulate the code into a method and call it on a post method in a view

Comment: so I could import the method into my views.py and just call that method with a POST or GET action?

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little broad for a specific answer, but in general, one can:

1. Have the button access an API which will, on the server, in another thread, your `main.py` file.
2. Once the application is finished, move the generated files to a deterministic location that serves static files on your web server.
3. Provide the user a URL to the newly created file's location.
4. Have a cron job run to clear out old files in the static directory.

Comment: Great, thank you. So I need to write an API to kick off the process? Are there any resources to help me do this?

Comment: @CecilJames [Celery](https://realpython.com/blog/python/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/) may be able to help you with that.